# Can not make an array out of an imported json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to make an array from a file, like this:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

var results = [];

fs.readFile('myfile.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    results = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(results); This works file
});

console.log('results length:', results.length);    
for ( r in results) { 
    console.log('res', r);
    console.log(r.configuration.value);
}
```

I can see the json object is printed out in the console.

However when I want to access outside `fs.readFile` , I get

```
results length: 0
```

And the loop does not itterate.

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use `readFileSync()` or put the code that uses `results` into the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar using  `fs.readFileSync` does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: Update the question and show how you rewrote it using `readFileSync()`.

Comment: `results = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myfile.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}));`

Comment: Right, this forumal works. Please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: To understand your `console.log('results length:', results.length);` was running before the result was returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` is asynchronous, and you're trying to use `results` before it has completed.

Use `fs.readFileSync()` instead of `fs.readFile()`

```
var results = JSON.parse(fs.readFile('myfile.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Read more about Node callbacks. https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/

Or, better, try async/await version of fs functions.